Why does spell & grammar check flag 'himself' as incorrect in this sentence?
"Finding a stream to clean himself after the first encounter had taken nearly two hours."
MS Word spell and grammar check keeps highlighting 'himself' as an error, but I can't find anything wrong with the sentence. can somebody explain what am I doing wrong here?
Here is a screen shot:


I checked with MS 365 also, with both US and UK english, and I got no underline. What is your language setting for spell check? What does it tell you when you right-click this word at the top of the context menu, is the top item 'Grammar'? If it's not, then it's invalid, as sometimes it makes a mistake, and the underline will go away after a while, or when you close and re-open the doc.

For me, on two separate computers, neither MS Word 2013 nor Word 2023 show any grammar or spelling errors (rightly so, as there are none). Usually, Word provides an explanation for flagging errors if you right click them; was one available to you?

It is possible that a very formal person might prefer '"Finding a stream in which to clean himself after the first encounter had taken nearly two hours.", but I do not think that MS Word is clever enough for that.

@MichaelHarvey Have added the screenshot of the highlight and the explanation. (Using MS Word 2010, if it matters))

My guess (wearing a software developer hat for a bit) is that Word seems to be getting confused over there not being a personal subject to refer back to in the sentence - or maybe there's something in the rest of the context that suggests a different subject. I'd see if "had taken him nearly two hours" would cause it to stop complaining (not that your sentence is wrong, though, so if you prefer your phrasing, you can likely stick to it).

@MaciejStachowski 'him' is the alternative suggested by the software, although that would not fit with the context at all. So, there are no mistakes in the sentence itself right? (other than what MichaelHarvey suggested.)

No, I mean to add "him" in the other part of the sentence and keep "himself" where it is - Word's suggestion would change the meaning of the sentence to imply someone else was looking for the stream. But in general, yes, I don't see a mistake here, and Word's grammar checker compared to its spellcheck is really more of a suggestion.

I guess maybe the grammar checker got an overhaul between 2010 and 2013.

I’m voting to close this question because we're not here to debug worthless software grammar checkers

@FumbleFingers Well, I think this isn't appropriate - not the software's manufacturer is asking the question to fix their product, but a language learner, and how would they know that the software is wrong? To be sure, they asked for volunteer's verification. Where else they should be asking?

@YonKuma: Why propose any changes at all? The text is fine as it is, and I don't see much point in debating whether it's somehow "improved" by adding unnecessary extra words (...stream in which to clean himself, ...stream to clean himself in). But obviously I think neither of those represent improvements on the original.

@Dávid Laczkó: Software grammar checkers are not intended to help learners write valid English! They're there for native Anglophones, to nudge the writer when he may have made an obvious slip-up. Learners shouldn't be encouraged to think of them as teaching aids. I believe that so far, that constraint also applies to online AI's. Currently, I think questions asking whether chatgpt / gemini / etc. are giving sound advice are Off Topic everywhere on Stack Exchange.

@FumbleFingers You're right, the sentence is fine as is. I retract my suggestion.

@FumbleFingers OK, then it's a separate problem on its own.

@DávidLaczkó: The only problem I see is that some people assume MS Word spell and grammar check knows what it's talking about. And / or that that this is suitable way to learn a foreign language.
